# structural stability

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems

Hi!

Can somebody help me with the following problem. How to prove that map f(x)=asin(x) where a is constant is not structurally C^r stable for any r in  N.

Comment: ivo, when a\in (0,1), consider h=asin(x)+0.3183. Then compare the fixed points. I can't see why this question is hard to solve    

Comment: Niyazi, to prove that f is not structurally stable I need to construct for every c>0 function g such that C^r distance between f and g is less than c and such that there is no top. conjugacy between f and g. In your answer you constructed such function for c=0.3183. This is not enough

Comment: ivo, it was just an example. use $c/2.$ you just need to shift graphs by $c/2$ then the C^r distance between new function and the old one will be small. The number of fixed points is not preserved. It will show that whatever c>0 is given, one can construct a new close function which is not top. conjugate with the original function. 

Comment: Niyazi, if a is between 0 and 1 then our f has only one fixed point right? If I make a small perturbation of f this map has also one fixed point, because the derivation of map x-f(x)-c is always greater than zero, this map will be increasing and therefore we will have only one zero

Comment: Ivo, the domain and range of your map is not clear, and you should give motivation and context to your question.

Comment: Benoit, map f is from R to R

Answer (score -1):

Let $S$ be the set of points where $f' = 0$. Then $f(S)$ consists of just two points.

This property is preserved by any topological conjugacy, but it won't be true of a generic tiny perturbation of $f$.

Comment: Can you please explain why is this property preserved by topological conjugacy since conjugacy is only homeo and it doesn't have to be derivable

Comment: Equivalently, define $S$ to be the set of points where $f$ is not locally a homeomorphism.